# Vertical centering doesn't seem to work using some typefaces in Chrome for mobile

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, typeface, font-family

i don't understand why seems impossible to center vertically inside a container elements as headings , paragraph , span .. using some typefaces in Chrome for mobile.Seems to work better in Firefox for mobile instead.
An example :
Open-Sans  works both on Firefox mobile and Chrome Mobile.Center vertically  using font family Raleway , for example , seems possible with Firefox mobile only.

```css
    #x-wrapper {
      
      position:absolute;
      left:100px;
      font-family:'Open Sans',sans-serif;font-weight:400;
      
     }
    
    #y-wrapper {
      position:absolute;
      left:200px;
      font-family:'Oswald',sans-serif;font-weight:400;
     }
    
    .circle {
      width:50px;
      height:50px;
      border:1px black solid;
      border-radius:25px;
      }
      
      .hello{
        position:relative;
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
       }
      
      .hello h5 {
        position:absolute;
        top:50%;
        left:50%;
        transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
        margin:0px;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="x-wrapper" class="circle">
      <div class="hello">
        <h5>hello</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="y-wrapper" class="circle">
      <div class="hello">
        <h5>hello</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

I would comment to ask questions, but not enough rep yet :/

Have you tried something like this:

```
.circle {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

using [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), they can be very useful when trying to vertically align text elements. Flexbox is also compatibly with most browsers: [link](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for the answer Alfie but doesn't resolve that issue. Doesn't seem related to the code used for centering element but to something else instead.
I wrote another piece of code trying to explain my problem in a better way.

```css
   #Oswald {
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;font-weight:400;
   }
   
   #Raleway {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;font-weight:600;
   }
   
   #Open-Sans {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;font-weight:600;
   }
   .title {
    padding-bottom:15px;
   }
   .circle {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border:1px solid black;
    border-radius:25px;
   }
     
   .hello-flex {
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
     }
      
   .hello-abs  {
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
   }
   
   .hello-abs span{
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    }
    
   span {
     margin:0px;
     font-size:10px;
     }
   
   .separator {
    padding:15px 0px;
   }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 </head>
 <body>
 <section id="Oswald">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row"> 
    <div class="col-xs-12">
     <div class="title text-center">
      <h1>Oswald</h1>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
     <div class="circle center-block">
      <div class="hello-flex">
       <span>HELLO</span>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div><!-- end col -->
    <div class="col-xs-6">
     <div class="circle center-block">
      <div class="hello-abs">
       <span>HELLO</span>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div> <!-- end col -->
   </div> <!-- end row -->
  </div> <!-- end container -->
 </section>
 <div class="separator"></div>
 <section id="Raleway">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row"> 
    <div class="col-xs-12">
     <div class="title text-center">
      <h1>Raleway</h1>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
     <div class="circle center-block">
      <div class="hello-flex">
       <span>HELLO</span>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div><!-- end col -->
    <div class="col-xs-6">
     <div class="circle center-block">
      <div class="hello-abs">
       <span>HELLO</span>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div> <!-- end col -->
   </div> <!-- end row -->
  </div> <!-- end container --> 
 </section>
 <div class="separator"></div>
 <section id="Open-Sans">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row"> 
    <div class="col-xs-12">
     <div class="title text-center">
      <h1>Open-Sans</h1>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
     <div class="circle center-block">
      <div class="hello-flex">
       <span>HELLO</span>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div><!-- end col -->
    <div class="col-xs-6">
     <div class="circle center-block">
      <div class="hello-abs">
       <span>HELLO</span>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div> <!-- end col -->
   </div> <!-- end row -->
  </div> <!-- end container --> 
 </section>
 </body>
</html>
```

That's the output in Chrome 48.0.2564.95 for Android :

[image]

Using Raleway font family Chrome seems to add some extra white space below text . Is there a way to fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

This problem *might* be caused by non-Latin characters in the font. Essentially, it's not a CSS issue but the actual font that has this additional space between the characters and the baseline.

Try adding this to your @font-face declaration:

```css
@font-face {
    /* latin only */
    unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}
```

If you're self hosting the font, you can also run the source font file (e.g. ttf) through [Font Squirrel's Webfont Generator](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) and choose Latin-only subsetting which would also have the benefit of a smaller font file.